# Evaluation of $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos 7x}}dx$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos 7x}}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos 7x}}dx$$

Now Put $\sin x\cos 7x = t^2\;,$ Then $(-7\sin x\sin 7x+\cos 7x\cos x)dx=2tdt$

Now How can I solve after that, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: Are sure that it isn't $$\cos^7x?$$  Then we can use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883963/find-the-integral-int-sin-x-11-3-cos-x-1-3dx

Comment: I agree with lab bhattacharjee's idea. Otherwise, I really do not see any approach for the posted problem (even using special functions).

Comment: By virtue of Mathematica, the integral can only be expressed in terms of the Incomplete Elliptic Integral of the Third Kind, making a closed form extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

The function inside the integral (as currently given) has multiple discontinuities where it approaches infinity then becomes purely imaginary then repeats. As such it is highly unlikely that a closed form exists.

[image]