# How to calculate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos^7x}}dx$?

Tags: integration

How to calculate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos^7x}}dx$? I found [Evaluation of $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos 7x}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905043/evaluation-of-int-frac1-sqrt-sin-x-cos-7xdx) a problem, but the link is not valid.

Comment: Do you know beta function?

Comment: @taritgoswami: that would be applicable if the integral were definite with bounds $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos^7 x}}dx=\int\frac{\sec^4x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx\\
=\int\frac{1+\tan^2x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}d\tan x$$